# Make os.path.expandvars expand like in shell

Tags: python, shell

I want to expand envs in [python](/questions/tagged/python) like shell does.

So here's my code:

```py
>>> os.path.expandvars("'$PATH'")
"'/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl'"
```

While in shell:

```sh
$ echo '$PATH'
$PATH
```

---

## UPDATE #1

To be more clear, I don't want `expandvars` to expand the strings in single quotes, because shell does not expand them.

## UPDATE #2

I want to achieve something like this:

```
>>> os.path.expandvars("$USER '$USER'")
"rapiz $USER"
```

Comment: Try without quotes `echo $PATH`. And, if you want to do it with quotes, use the double quotes: `echo "$PATH"`.

Comment: Shell processing is *really* complicated and full of lots of different processing rules, and it's not clear which parts of that you want. The shell quoting rules are harder to separate from the other parts of shell processing than you might think.

Comment: To be more clear, I don't want `expandvars` expand strings in quotes.

Comment: [@rapiz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8702537/rapiz), about "expand strings in quotes", take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60629885/2039993).

Comment: Okay. What about backslashes? With shell variable `X` set to `asdf`, `echo \$X` will echo `X`, while `os.path.expandvars(r'\$x')` will return `"\\asdf"`. What behavior do you want there?

Comment: Which shell are you talking about? There are many shells and they behave differently. See also the description of the "shell" tag that you applied. Please also don't litter your question with "edit" sections. If people were interested in the history of it, they could check it themselves.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I think shell generally refers to POSIX compliant shells.

Comment: Can't you just join the string `'$USER'` after getting the output from `expandvars`?

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

`expandvars` deliberately expands the path, quoting from python [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expandvars):

> Unlike a unix shell, Python does not do any automatic path expansions. Functions such as expanduser() and expandvars() can be invoked explicitly when an application desires shell-like path expansion. (See also the glob module.)

If you want to replicate the shell command exactly, you can use `os.popen`:

```
import os

output = os.popen("echo '$PATH'").read()
```

Comment: your `output` will be `'$PATH\n'`

Comment: It works. But I think it's not good enough because if the strings comes from users' input, it will cause a vulnerability.

Comment: Which string comes directly from the user? `'$USER'`?

Comment: I think it's the best solution I can find. Thought it has some drawbacks,it's simple and effective.

Answer (score 0):

> While in shell,
>
> ```
> $ echo '$PATH'
> $PATH
> ```

There is also the same output, if you won't use quotes, like

```sh
echo $PATH
```

Also, in python you can use

```py
>>> os.path.expandvars('$PATH')
'/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl'

# or

>>> print(os.path.expandvars('$PATH'))
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
```

---

Also, I feel you have a bit misunderstanding with working in python interactive shell, therefore I add a few lines below.

```py
>>> import os
>>> my_envs = os.path.expandvars('$PATH')
>>> my_envs # Look at this output
'/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl'
>>> print(my_envs) # And look at this output
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
```

Do you see difference in the outputs?

---

## Update #1

@rapiz wrote:

> ## UPDATE #2
>
> I want to achieve something like this:
>
> ```py
> >>> os.path.expandvars("$USER '$USER'")
> "rapiz $USER"
> ```

How about solution below?

```py
>>> user_env = '$USER'
>>> user_env_val = os.path.expandvars(user_env)
>>> print(f'"{user_env_val} {user_env}"')
"rapiz $USER"
```

Comment: Well, I think I understand the difference between print and values returned. Hopefully, UPDATE #2 can make the question more clear.

Comment: "rapiz, I added and fixed Update #1